# how to optimize this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

How to optimize this functions? Can I make one function for all operations?

```js
$('#b-hat1').click(function() {
  $('#hat3').hide();
  $('#hat2').hide();
  $('#hat1').show();
});
$('#b-hat2').click(function() {
  $('#hat3').hide();
  $('#hat2').show();
  $('#hat1').hide();
});
$('#b-hat3').click(function() {
  $('#hat3').show();
  $('#hat2').hide();
  $('#hat1').hide();
});
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code to the question so we can see how the `#b-hatX` relate to the `#hatX` elements

Comment: add your HTML code

Comment: Probably by not using IDs in the first place (that's why you've been asked for HTML, since it's the most relevant bit).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without your html, i can only give you a "rought" idea about how to solve it.

`$("div[id^='hat']").hide();` hides all the div's that starts with `hat`

```js
$('div[id^="b-hat"]').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("b-","");
  $("div[id^='hat']").hide();
  $('#' + id).show(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hat1">hat1</div>
<div id="hat2">hat2</div>
<div id="hat3">hat3</div>
<br><br>

<div id="b-hat1">Show hat1</div>
<div id="b-hat2">Show hat2</div>
<div id="b-hat3">Show hat3</div>
```

Comment: what doing this operator '^=' ?

Comment: The `^=` in `id^='hat` means it takes all `id's` that starts with "hat"

Comment: Is there a list of such operators? Would be helpful to know. By the way why did you not use data attributes

Comment: @sinhavartika There is a list here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ 

There is no reason to use data-attributes when you can easy create what the op wanted without

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks .. would it be a good practice to do it with data attribs? Just wanted to know .. because it used to be my way.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with data attributes, but I don't see a reason to use them if they are not needed

Comment: Always wanted to avoid making so many ids ... anyway .. got you point! thanks!

Comment: okay @CarstenLovboAndersen,Will ***=** also work same as like **^=**

Answer (score 7):

Will show the div only after click on particular button
**DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hat").hide();
    $(".clickMe").on("click",function(){
       var showDiv = $(this).data("id");       
       $(".hat").hide();
       $("#hat_"+showDiv).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clickMe" data-id="1" type="button">1</button>
<button class="clickMe" data-id="2" type="button">2</button>
<button class="clickMe" data-id="3" type="button">3</button>

<div id="hat_1" class="hat">hat_1</div>
<div id="hat_2" class="hat">hat_2</div>
<div id="hat_3" class="hat">hat_3</div>
```

Comment: this should be the approved answer