# Same function with different numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

who can help me?
I have 30 buttons if you click on button 1 element 1 has to show if you click on button 2 element 2 has to show. and so on

now i don't want to put the same code 30 times (example 1) with only different numbers. I think it can be shorter (example 2)

Does anyone know how I can best do this?

example 1:

```
$("#O1").click(function() {
  KSlevel = 1;
  alert(KSlevel);
  $('#ks' + KSlevel).fadeIn(200);
});

$("#O2").click(function() {
  KSlevel = 2;
  alert(KSlevel);
  $('#ks' + KSlevel).fadeIn(200);
});
```

example2:

```
$("#OX").click(function() {
  KSlevel = X;
  alert(KSlevel);
  $('#ks' + KSlevel).fadeIn(200);
});
```

Comment: You can easily genericise this, but it depends on how your HTML is structured; how do the buttons relate to the elements you fade in? Could you please show a short example of the HTML in the question.

Comment: Well you could do `KSlevel= $(this).attr("id").replace("O","");` and `$( "[id^=O]" ).click(` you can look at this example, it will point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411120/how-to-optimize-this-javascript-code/42411271#42411271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="test" id="1">click</button>
<p id="p1" style="display: none;">1</p>

<button class="test" id="2">click</button>
<p id="p2" style="display: none;">2</p>

<button class="test" id="3">click</button>
<p id="p3" style="display: none;">3</p>

<button class="test" id="4">click</button>
<p id="p4" style="display: none;">4</p>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.test').click((e)=>{
     $(`#p${e.target.id}`).fadeIn();
});
```

You can also run a function on *HTML's onClick* attribute and put an id in the function's parameter. Rest of the function would be the same.